# How to have two different responses depending on the first string?

Tags: java

EDIT for a little bit more clearance:

I think what the code should do is: "If I put 0 as first on the "scanner", the text "you cant count the ones" should pop up.

But if I have typed some other numbers into scanner first, it should "break;" the program and print ONLY out the calculations that are at the bottom. Not the "you cant count the ones".

I seem to get one part of the two working, but not the both.

I've tried moving the if-sentences around, and moving `System.out.println`'s around.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

    int yksi = 0;
    int numero = 0;

    while (true) {
        int luku = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());

        if (luku == 0) {
            System.out.println("you cant count the ones");
            break;
        }

        if (luku == 1) {
            yksi = yksi + 1;
        } else if (luku != 0) { 
            numero = numero + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(1.0 * yksi / (numero + yksi));
}
```

Comment: What did you mean by "when you input 0 first"?

Comment: do you want to `continue;`?

Comment: As an aside: In this case, you should use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) instead of [`Integer.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @Sand I mean that when you write "0" first, I'd like it to answer only "you cant count the ones", and not the last one with the calculations. "0" is also used to break; if there's other numbers used before it, and then it should not print "you cant count the ones", but only the last thing on the code.

Comment: If I write 0 first it should break also? while printing "you cant count the ones"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to `break` when you first type `0` and only display the message "you cant count the ones". Then you can use a flag like this and put the break inside the else part,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

    int yksi = 0;
    int numero = 0;
    boolean flag = true;

    while (true) {
        int luku = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());

        if (luku == 0) {
            if (flag) {
                System.out.println("you cant count the ones");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        flag = false;

        if (luku == 1) {
            yksi = yksi + 1;
        } else if (luku != 0) {
            numero = numero + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(1.0 * yksi / (numero + yksi));
}
```